# Error #1064 in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Can anyone tell me why PHPMyAdmin throws out the Error #1064?

**MySQL Query:**

```
CREATE TABLE posts 
  ( ID not null auto_increment unsigned int, 
    pType enum('article', 'link') not null, 
    Title text null, 
    Link text null, 
    BodyMD longtext null, 
    BodyHT longtext not null, 
    URL tinytext not null, 
    ShortURL tinytext not null, 
    status enum('drafted', 'published') not null, 
    DateEdited timestamp null, 
    DatePublished timestamp null, 
    Topic enum('') null, 
    primary key (ID, URL, ShortURL) 
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the column type *before* constraints and attributes, and the correct type is `int unsigned`, not `unsigned int`:

```
...
ID int unsigned not null auto_increment,
...
```

Comment: Thanks! That improved, but it's still giving me the same error code. Weird.

Comment: You probably haven't updated your query correctly, as it _doesn't_ give the same code when fixed. It gives error 1170, because the `URL tinytext` column is used in a primary key without specified length (i.e. you need to have `primary key (ID, URL(50), ShortURL(50))`, for example) — MySQL does not index arbitrary length text columns without explicit index length limit.